# 403 forbidden and 400 bad request errors while adding and deleting items to SharePoint list using REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to SharePoint development. I'm Trying to develop  simple SharePoint App using SharePoint online. I have a List named 'Products' in my site collection. In my app I wrote the following code to add and delete items to that list

```
 function addProduct(product) {
 var executor;
 executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appwebUrl);
 var url = appwebUrl +"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items/?@target='" + hostwebUrl+"'";
 executor.executeAsync({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({__metadata: { type: 'SP.Data.ProductsListItem' },
        Title: product.ProductName(),
        ProductId: product.ProductId(),
        ProductName: product.ProductName(),
        Price:product.Price()
    }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
    success: successProductAddHandler,
    error: errorProductAddHandler
});
}


function successProductAddHandler(data) {alert('added successfully') }
function errorProductAddHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) { alert('cannot perform action') }


function deleteProduct(product) {
var executor;
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appwebUrl);
var url=appwebUrl+"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items('" + product.ID() + "')/?@target='" + hostwebUrl + "'";
executor.executeAsync({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {

        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
    },
    success: successProductAddHandler,
    error: errorProductAddHandler
});`
```

Im getting `403` error code when I call `addProduct`,
and `400` error code when I call `deleteProduct`.
I'm able to get the list items and display.

I tried adding  `X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()` but it did not work

If I include `"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"` in a request header for `deleteProduct()`, and when I call `deleteProduct`, two requests are going to server

1. `/sites/productsdev/productsapp/_api/contextinfo` (getting digest value)
2. `/sites/ProductsDev/ProductsApp/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items(itemid)/?@target='mysitecollectionurl'`  (using the digest value returned by the above call for `X-RequestDigest`)

Comment: Oh.. got the solution. 
In AppManifest.xml permissions tab I gave only read permission to scope 'web'.
So i can only do get requests, now i changed It to 'Full Control', Working Perfectly.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that the updated code?

Comment: So is this in any way possible as an embedded code block within a page on SharePoint Online 2013?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435432/sharepoint-2013-via-rest-api-error-403-forbidden-when-trying-to-create-item Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32824960/5243272

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are doing any POST operation in SharePoint 2013 using REST API you have to pass below snippet in header

> "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

eg

> headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>           "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  }