# REST HTTP POST to SharePoint List with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http-post, sharepoint-2013

I'm using angularjs to create a simple SPA which allows users to interact with a Bookings list in Hosted SharePoint 2013.

I've got the HTTP GET working fine and retrieving bookings for various filtered queries.

However, now I want to Insert and Update records into the list, but Fiddler shows an 'HTTP Error 403' occurred and the following under JSON tab:

> value=The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.

I would appreciate some help confirming the following code should work. A Submit button on new booking form triggers the post:

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
  //new booking
    if ($scope.editableBooking.Id == 0) {
        service.insertBooking($scope.editableBooking, function (data) {
            $scope.editableBooking = data;
        });
    }
  // Update booking
    else {
        console.log("[submitForm] Update");
        service.updateBooking($scope.editableBooking, function (data) {
            $scope.editableBooking = data;
            console.log('[updatedBooking] id = ' + $scope.editableBooking.Id)
        });
    }
}
```

Within my factory I have a service to insert booking:

```
var insertBooking = function (newBooking, callback) {
    console.log('[insertBooking] Id = ' + newBooking.Id + " Storeno = " + newBooking.Storeno);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Bookings')",
        data: $.param({
            Title: newBooking.Storeno,
            Description: newBooking.Description,
            BookedBy: newBooking.Bookedby,
            StartDate: newBooking.StartDate
        }),
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("[insertBooking] POST worked");
        console.log('[insertbooking] New Id = ' + data.Id);

        callback(data);

    }).error(function (er) {
        console.log('[insertBooking] Error = ' + er);
    });
}
```

---

Searching StackOverFlow is this post on [Error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193290/403-forbidden-and-400-bad-request-errors-while-adding-and-deleting-items-to-shar) which talks about the AppManifest. I don't have access to this file - it's on a corporate intranet - and I haven't built an installable app, just angularjs files called via a CEWP.

Any suggestions please on how to update a SP list?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same error in the past

> The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.

I found this [blog](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript) by Wictor Wilén that explains how to refresh the digest token.

Basically you insert this line before your `$http` invocation:

```
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval);
```

Some main points from the blog:

- This method is synchronous, so there's no need to worry about callbacks etc.
- it uses an update interval and only updates the form digest when needed – so if your digest hasn't expired, there are no additional calls to SharePoint